# Couldn't find 'devise_install' generator - Rails 2.3.8, Devise 1.0.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to get Devise up and running with a freshly generated Rails 
2.3.8 app.

This is the error I'm running into:

```
devise > script/generate devise_install
Couldn't find 'devise_install' generator
```

I do have the Devise and Warden gems specified in my config file:

```
config.gem 'warden', :version => '0.10.7'
config.gem 'devise', :version => '1.0.8'
```

The gems are installed:

```
devise > rake gems 
 - [I] warden = 0.10.7
    - [R] rack >= 1.0.0
 - [I] devise = 1.0.8
    - [I] warden ~> 0.10.3
       - [R] rack >= 1.0.0
I = Installed
F = Frozen
R = Framework (loaded before rails starts)
```

Looking at the list of generators, I don't see anything from Devise:

```
devise > script/generate
Installed Generators
  Rubygems: cucumber, facebook, facebook_controller,
facebook_publisher, facebook_scaffold, feature, integration_spec,
publisher, rspec, rspec_controller, rspec_model, rspec_scaffold,
session, xd_receiver
  Builtin: controller, helper, integration_test, mailer, metal,
migration, model, observer, performance_test, plugin, resource,
scaffold, session_migration
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 6):

in 1.1.5 its
rails generate devise:install.  I have seen devise_install in some tutorials.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem myself and, unfortunately, didn't ever get it fixed. But I did manage to find a pretty simple workaround.

The tasks the generators perform are typically pretty straightforward. So manually reproducing the same result shouldn't be a big deal if you just [take a look at the generator code](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/v1.0/generators/).

The `devise_install` generator in your example above just copies [devise.rb](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.0/generators/devise_install/templates/devise.rb) to `config/initializers/devise.rb` and [en.yml](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v1.0/lib/devise/locales/en.yml) to `config/locales/devise.en.yml`

If you take a look at the other generators I'm sure you can figure them out easily enough as well.

Comment: This is correct. You do not even need the locals/en.yml file unless you want to customize the flash messages/errors

Answer (score 5):

The same problem occurred with me, because I'm already had installed devise (a version ahead of 1.0.8). I just uninstall the devise ahead version.

Now my enviroment has only devise 1.0.8 and it works very well. :)

Answer (score 0):

seems to be working using devise 1.0.7